# Sencha Touch Update Contents of a tabPanel with Buttons

Tags: button, sencha-touch, tabpanel

I've been trying to learn Sencha Touch and I'm stuck on something that is probably pretty obvious. I'm trying to update a tabPanel with a button event. I'd like for a tap on the first button to load 'maptestPanel' in the same panel. This is a map loaded from its own js file.

The map panel looks ok by itself:

```
 maptestPanel =  new Ext.Panel({
                      layout: 'fit',
                      fullscreen: true,
                      items: [map]
                  });
```

But I'm not seeing how to properly place it in the tabPanel

The code is:

```
Ext.setup({
    icon: 'icon.png',
    tabletStartupScreen: 'tablet_startup.png',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'phone_startup.png',
    glossOnIcon: false,
    onReady: function() {

    var navBar = new Ext.Toolbar({
        dock : 'top',
        title: 'Some App Name',
    });

    var topPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        dockedItems: [navBar],
        fullscreen : true,
        //html: 'Test Panel'
    });


    var tapHandler = function(button, event) {
            btnPanel.update(maptestPanel); //I'm sure part of the problem is here   
    }   


    var SomeDate1 = new Ext.Button({
        text:"Some date",
        minWidth:200,
        height: 45,
        cls:"listButtonTop",
        handler:tapHandler                  
        });

    var SomeDate2 = new Ext.Button({
        text:"Another Date",
        minWidth:200,
        height: 45,
        cls:"listButton"
    });

    var SomeDate3 = new Ext.Button({
        text:"And Another Date",
        minWidth:200,
        height: 45,
        cls:"listButtonBottom"
    });


    var btnPanel = new Ext.Panel ({
        id: 'date',
        items: [SomeDate1,SomeDate2,SomeDate3],         
    });

    var tabpanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
        layout: 'card',
        tabBar: {
            dock: 'bottom',
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            }
        },
        fullscreen: true,
        ui: 'dark',
        cardSwitchAnimation: {
            type: 'slide',
            cover: true
        },
        defaults: {
            scroll: 'vertical'
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Maps',
            //html: '<h1>Place holder</h1>',
            iconCls: 'maps',
            cls: 'card1',
            items: [btnPanel]               
        }, {
            title: 'Favs',
            html: '<h1>Place holder</h1>',
            iconCls: 'favorites',
            cls: 'card2',
            badgeText: '4',
            layout: 'fit'
            //items: [SomeList, SomeOtherList, AnotherList]
        }, {
           title: 'Info',
            html: '<h1>Place holder</h1>',
            cls: 'card4',
            iconCls: 'info'
        }]
    });
   }
});
```

Thanks for any advice or a steer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things you need to do to fix up that code:

1) 'Maps' has no layout. Since it has a single child item, layout: 'fit' would be appropriate here.

2) Only use fullscreen on the outermost item, you don't want the other items to be fullscreen since they are child items of other containers.

3) To dynamically add items to a container, use the add() method on container. You'll also need to call doLayout() to trigger a layout for the container.

```
btnPanel.add(maptestpanel);
btnPanel.doLayout();
```

However, in this case I don't see why you're adding the map to a panel, it doesn't give you any extra functionality. Instead, I would add the map directly to the btnPanel.

4) The btnPanel has no layout either, so you'll need to choose an appropriate layout there as well, possibly the vbox layout.

Comment: Thanks huge help! It's starting to make sense. I made those changes and ended up adding btnPanel.add(maptestpanel); btnPanel.doLayout(); and btnPanel.setActiveItem(3); to the handler. This is very close. It displays the map in a new tab but there is a light gray square on the toolbar (like an empty icon). Can that be removed easily?

Answer (score 0):

I only know "classic" sencha, but this should work the same way : So you could just add the mapPanel (but hidden) to your tabPanel, and in the button handler show it while hiding the button panel.

Besides, speaking of layouts, I don't think you need to precise layout:'card' in tabPanel since it uses a card layout by definition